# Chrome API to detect file downloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to write a Chrome extension to track file download dates and speeds.
Is there any Google Chrome API to detect when a file starts/ends downloading?

Thanks,
-J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at the time of writing.

The [Chrome extensions API documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) doesn't currently cover such functionality.

The [experimental downloads API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.downloads.html) doesn't cover the functionality you need but may be worth checking back on as changes are made.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Cram. I will monitor activity of [chrome.experimental.downloads](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.downloads.html).

Comment: Link to the "experimental downloads API" is broken! (I know the answer is old, but for other people)

Answer (score 2):

There's something in the pipe right now!

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Tracking starting and stopping can be done with onCreated/onChanged/search(), which are implemented and will probably be released out of experimental into the dev branch in a couple weeks or so. I'll make an announcement on the Google Chrome Developers G+ stream.

Tracking the speed of the download can be approximated, but the speed that is displayed in the shelf and chrome://downloads is not directly accessible via the extension api as currently spec'd. We'll consider exposing the information if there's a use case that can't be met well enough by approximation.

No firm plans yet on when the api will be released to the stable branch.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Hayden, this is good to hear. Approximation will cover my needs for now. -John